# Annotate one section of a facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to annotate one section of a plot:

```
region<-    c('vic',    'vic',  'vic',  'sa',   'vic',  'vic',  'sa',    
'sa',   'vic',  'sa',   'sa',   'sa',   'vic',  'vic',  'sa',   'sa')
year<-  c(2010, 2010,   2010,   2010,   2011,   2011,   2011,   2011,    
2010,   2010,   2010,   2010,   2011,   2011,   2011,   2011)
diveLocation<-  c('Comp',   'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp',  
'Comp', 'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',     
'Lease',    'Lease')
newy<-c('yes',  'yes',  'no',   'no',   'yes',  'no',   'yes',  'no',    
'no',   'yes',  'yes',  'yes',  'no',   'no',   'yes',  'yes')

df<- data.frame(region, year,   diveLocation,   newy)
```

which gives the following data frame:

```
region   year   diveLocation  newy
<fctr>   <fctr>  <fctr>       <fctr>

  vic   2010    Comp       yes  
  vic   2010    Comp       yes  
  vic   2010    Comp       no   
  sa    2010    Comp       no   
  vic   2011    Comp       yes  
  vic   2011    Comp       no   
  sa    2011    Comp       yes  
  sa    2011    Comp       no   
  vic   2010    Lease      no   
  sa    2010    Lease      yes
  sa    2010    Lease      yes  
  sa    2010    Lease      yes  
  vic   2011    Lease      no   
  vic   2011    Lease      no   
  sa    2011    Lease      yes  
  sa    2011    Lease      yes
```

the plot code:

```
 t<-df%>%
 ggplot(aes(x=region, fill = newy)) +
 geom_bar(stat = 'Count', position = 'stack') + 
 facet_grid(diveLocation~year) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Levels")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 10)) + #optional line
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) + 
 xlab("Region") + ylab("Count") + ggtitle("Noncompliance at both")

 t
```

with the plot

[image: facet plot]

I now want to place some text in one of the facets and have found others examples but can't get to work. For example:

```
 ann_text <- data.frame(y = 1,x = 2,lab = "Text",
                   year = factor(2011,levels = c('2010','2011'),
                                 diveLocation = factor(Lease, levels = 
c('Comp', 'Lease'))))

t+ann_text
```

But get the following error:
Error in factor(2011, levels = c("2010", "2011"), diveLocation = factor(Lease,  : 
  unused argument (diveLocation = factor(Lease, levels = c("Comp", "Lease")))

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I can't see the variable `Lease` in your example, perhaps it was `newy`?

Comment: it is an observation in diveLocation and newy is the yes and no obs

Comment: also I missed some data which is now in @Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your definition of `ann_text`. You also need to add an additional geom layer to the plot. Here's an example to get you started:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
region<-    c('vic',    'vic',  'vic',  'sa',   'vic',  'vic',  'sa',    
              'sa',   'vic',  'sa',   'sa',   'sa',   'vic',  'vic',  'sa',   'sa')
year<-  c(2010, 2010,   2010,   2010,   2011,   2011,   2011,   2011,    
          2010,   2010,   2010,   2010,   2011,   2011,   2011,   2011)
diveLocation<-  c('Comp',   'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp', 'Comp',  
                  'Comp', 'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',    'Lease',     
                  'Lease',    'Lease')
newy<-c('yes',  'yes',  'no',   'no',   'yes',  'no',   'yes',  'no',    
        'no',   'yes',  'yes',  'yes',  'no',   'no',   'yes',  'yes')

df<- data.frame(region, year,   diveLocation,   newy)
#You need to pass in values for all the aesthetics used in the main plot, i.e.
#region, newy, diveLocation, year.
ann_text <- data.frame(diveLocation = "Lease",
                       year = 2011,
                       newy = "yes",
                       x = "vic",
                       y = 5,
                       label = "your text here")


df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=region, fill = newy)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'Count', position = 'stack') + 
  facet_grid(diveLocation~year) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Levels")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 10)) + #optional line
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) + 
  xlab("Region") + ylab("Count") + ggtitle("Noncompliance at both") +
  geom_text(data = ann_text, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks Chase. Really appreciate your help. It will be handy to have n = etc on the ggplots!

Comment: just wondering if any one can explain why I had to edit @Chase 'ann_text' code with:  ann_text <- data.frame(diveLocation = "Lease",
                       year = 2011,
                       newy = factor(2,levels = c('yes','no')),
                       x = 3,
                       y = 5,
                       label = "your text here")    i.e. the factor to 'newy' to get the code to work with my actual data but it worked fine with the example and both had two levels of 'newy 'factor.

Comment: @Tom - check `str()` of the two objects and compare.

Comment: thanks again, I think it may have been due to not dropping levels when doing some earlier tidying